# Typo3 6.2 Goverment Package

Tags: typo3

After a long time i try today the Typo3 Version 6.2 LTS. In the earlier versions a goverment package of Typo3 was available.

Now i install the Version 6.2 and found in the extension manager a link called "Get preconfigured distribution", after i click this link i get the following distributios.

The official Introduction Package

The dotpulse Kickstart Package

og_base

Bootstrap Kickstart Package

t3onepage

Code-Source Introduction Package

A goverment package distribution is not available, how can i install a goverment package? Should i use a old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was available unter typo3.org/download but it seems they have removed the link. Anyway they wrote you can use the service described under get.typo3.org

like
wget get.typo3.org/government -O typo3_src.tgz

--> this gives you version 6.1.7 so you have to update it manually to 6.2 <--

cheers